# How to read formulas for binary relations

Tags: notation, relations

As an example of a set, I make the following notation: `X = {1,2,3}`

For comparison, I take the formulas of reflexivity and symmetry.

The first formula should be understood as (as I think):

[image]

For each x that belongs to the set X, the relation must contain a pairs `(x, x) ∈ R`. That is, the meaning is this: no matter how many elements we have in the set X, the reflexive relation is only that which contains a pair for each element X in the relation R, therefore `R = {(1,1)}` - not correct, but correct `R = {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)}`

The second formula should be understood as (as I think):

[image]

For each x and y that belong to the set X, the relation should contain pairs that are inverse to each other `(x, y) ∈ R => (y, x) ∈ R`. By this conclusion, a relation is drawn in my head approximately as with a property of reflexivity, but with the rules of symmetry, that is, the wrong relation will be: `R = {(1,1)}`, but correct is `R = {(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), ( 2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)}` - all Cartesian product.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reflexive, it must contain all the pairs $xRx$, so your last example is correct.  It can contain any other pairs desired, so $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(2,3)\}$ is reflexive as well.

For symmetric, note that it says $aRb \implies bRa$.  If $aRb$ is not true it does not impose a requirement.  Both your examples are symmetric, as is the empty relation.  Another that is symmetric is $\{(1,2),(2,1),(3,3)\}$

Comment: But wait, the formulas do not say what restrictions are present. Well, for example, for reflexivity: it is not said that a pair or pairs can be present in addition to those that correspond to the property of reflexivity (you gave an example). Well, also for the symmetry property: it is not said that there may not be pairs at all. Since I perceive `∀a, b` as absolutely all values (each) ​​from the set X, I don’t understand how they can be absent and correspond to symmetry. I'm confused.

Comment: Symmetry says for every pair $(a,b)$ that is in the relation $(b,a)$ is also in the relation, but it does not require any at all.  It is true that $\forall a,b$ covers all values for each, but what it asserts is an implication.  If the antecedent is false, the implication is true.  Another example is equality.  On your set, it corresponds to $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$  This is symmetric despite the lack of $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$

Comment: That is, this symbol (⟹) here means the action of implication (I know what an implication is)? Then what then would be a `false` as an antecedent within the set X? And you said: "but what it asserts is an implication" - what this means, explain.

Comment: It means whatever you pick for $a,b$, you have $aRb \implies bRa$.  If I have the relation $\{(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)\}$ we can check that it is symmetric.  If we choose $a=1,b=1,$ we have $aRb$ and $bRa$ are both true, so the implication is true.  If we choose $a=1,b=3$ we have $aRb$ and $bRa$ are both false, so the implication is true.  You can go through all the other possibilities and see the implication is always true, so the relation is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you, now it’s completely clear.